# How to do a groupby follow by order by and then pick the first row in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I want to group by two columns and then order by a third column and then pick the first row from each group. This is the code I'm using

```
first= df.groupby(['EMPLID','EMPL_RCD']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = ['EFFDT','EFFSEQ'], ascending = True)).first()
```

but I'm getting the following error when running it

```
first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `sort_values` and then `drop_duplicates`:

```
res = df.sort_values(['EFFDT','EFFSEQ'])\
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['EMPLID','EMPL_RCD'])
```

Alternatively, you can sort and then use `groupby` + `first`:

```
res = df.sort_values(['EFFDT','EFFSEQ'])\
        .groupby(['EMPLID','EMPL_RCD']).first()
```

Your code does not work because you are applying `first` to a dataframe rather than a `GroupBy` object. You need to pass `first` to `groupby` as an aggregating function.

Comment: Thanks for this hint "Your code does not work because you are applying first to a dataframe rather than a GroupBy object. You need to pass first to groupby as an aggregating function."